# Match an expression that has a descendant pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, searching

I have a complicated expression in which I have another expression *p* which, when it’s present, I want to match the outer expression and all of its children. I was hoping for something like `Descendant[p]` which matches *p* if it appears anywhere in the child tree of the expression. For example:

```
X = ElementA[a,b,c,
   ElementB[{1,2,3,
      ElementC[c,d,
         ElementD[foo]
      ]
   }]
]
```

Where:

```
MatchQ[X, ElementA[Descendant[foo]]]
```

Would match the entire expression `ElementA[...]` because `foo` appears somewhere as a descendant.

Comment: Something like `MatchQ[X, e : ElementA[args__] /; ! FreeQ[e, foo]]`?

Comment: ... or `MatchQ[X, _ElementA?(Not@*FreeQ[foo])]`